# I can't see metada of my Facebook canvas application

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-canvas

First of all I can't post any specific info about project because it has to be secret till going live.

I'm struggling with my Facebook canvas application. I set up everything correctly, and added App Namespace, lets say 'some_namespace'.

So my app would be accessible under this URL: http://apps.facebook.com/some_namespace/

When I check this URL in debugger (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) it works perfectly! I see all the metadata (image, title, description and others)

But see attached images - I can't see anything there:/

[image: popup on the rhs of canvas application]

[image: popup when rollover the name of the app on my wall]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First one started to work when I generated second using activity, so probably fb cache issue, or lack of data several hours ago
2. Second one started to work after I specified App info details (with 180px image) on app profile page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to lint the url of your app page, not the facebook url. Do you get any different results from that?

Comment: I lint also app page, and its workin fine, but still dont have what I need :/

Comment: hey Abby, thanks for attention, I edited my question and provided some fix which works for me.